# Dropdown menu always collapse on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Usually for a DropDown menu you would expect that when you chose an option the menu collapse, however this is not my case. I don't want to collapse the dropdown menu if the user tries to login and click on Username and Password:

http://www.filmgratuiti.org/streamingembed2.php?nome=jobs

I remember it worked a while ago probably it's about the CSS, which I have cleaned up in the meantime.
Is there an easy way of doing it?

P.S: I don't know why but it looks like i can't share clickable link ...

Comment: Make some fiddle, so we can test it.

Comment: I'll make it right now

Comment: Weird thing but with the fiddle is kind of working [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5Hgcz/2/) I guess I will just have to to open up firebug and disable every rule one at a time to find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
HTML

```
<div class="signup" >
<a href="#">LOGIN</a>  
</div>

<div class="login_form  ">
<form method="post" action="#">
<p>Email</p>
<p><input type="email" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Email"></p>
<p>Password</p>
<p><input type="password" name="password" class="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
<br>
<p><span><input type="checkbox" name="check" class="check" style="vertical-align:middle;">Remember me</span><span class="login_btn" ><a href="#">Login</a></span> </p>

</form>
</div><!-- login_form -->
```

CSS

```
.signup
{
background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
width:25%;
height:25px;
border-color:rgb(221,221,221);
border-width:1px;

-moz-border-radius:1px;

-webkit-border-radius:1px;

border-radius:1px;
border-style:solid;
text-align:center;
padding:9px 8px 0 5px;
margin-top:10px;

}

.signup a
{color:#444444;
font-size:0.9375em;
text-decoration:none;
}


.login_form
{   

width:50%;
    height:auto;

padding:10px 0 0 0;

position:absolute !important;


}

.login_form p
{line-height:150%;
font-size:0.875em;
color:#535353;
padding-left:5px;

}

.email, .password
{border:1px solid #D9D8D7;
width:96%;
}

.login_btn
{
display:block;


width:80%;
padding:3px 0 5px 0;
border-color:rgb(242,128,8);
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;

text-align:center;
margin-bottom:2px;

}

.login_btn a
{color:#fff;
}
```

JS

```
$(".login_form").hide();

$(".signup, .login_form").click(function(e) {
    $(".login_form").show();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return true;

   });


  $(document).click(function(){  
  $('.login_form').hide(); //hide the form

  });
```

here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7tHQ/1/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to make it work. I'll let you know

Comment: There's a jquery confict somewhere in my page, i just have to find it